# <label> for attribute selectors with duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'm using the bx-slider for a project I'm working on and I recently found out that it creates clones of the first and last input elements placing them in their respective spots to give the slider an "infinite" effect.

This is great however when I'm using labels in the last one, it doesn't work as the for attribute on *both* labels will get the first input, which respectively is the clone.

Is there any way I can use jQuery/CSS selectors in the for attribute? (Example: `<label for="isActive28:last">`)

Due to request, here is a quick jsfiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/YG9u9/1/

Comment: Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo please?

Comment: @FelixKling In the OP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just drop `for=""` entirely, in favor of wrapping the labels around the inputs:

`<label>Level: <input type="text" name="level1" id="level1" /></label>`

This will perform the same function but without needing to care about the actual ID name at all, thus solving the problem. You can clone that all you want and that label will still reference the input or select it surrounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I surprisingly didn't know you could do this.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks jquery-ui checkboxes